# How to show that a surface has directional derivative the same as tangent plane in all directions

Tags: calculus

Let $Z(x,y)$ be continuously differentiable, let $L(x,y)$ be the equation of the tangent plane to $Z(x,y)$ at $(x_0,y_0)$. Show that the directional derivative of L is the same as the directional derivative of Z at $(x_0,y_0)$ for all directions.

I can see that $L(x_0,y_0)$ and $Z(x_0, y_0)$ must have the same value.

I need to show that:

$\nabla_{\alpha}L(x_0,y_0) = \nabla_{\alpha}Z(x_0,y_0)$ for all $\alpha$

Moreover I need to show that:

$L_x(x_0,y_0)cos(\alpha) + L_y(x_0,y_0)sin(\alpha)=Z_x(x_0,y_0)cos(\alpha) + Z_y(x_0,y_0)sin(\alpha)$

So I need to show that $L_x(x_0,y_0) = Z_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $L_y(x_0,y_0) = Z_y(x_0,y_0)$

I can imagine this intuitively, anything else would mean that $L(x,y)$ would not be tangent to $Z(x,y)$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ but I can't see how to show it algebraically.

Thanks for any help.

Being thinking it through further, would the following be correct?

We can write $L(x,y)$ as $L(x,y) = Z(x_0, y_0) + (x - x_0)Z_x(x_0,y_0) + (y-y_0)Z_y(x_0,y_0)$

and differentiating both sides wrt to x (y held constant) and then y (x held constant) we immediately obtain:

$L_x=Z_x(x_0, y_0)$ and $L_y=Z_y(x_0, y_0)$

which implies that:

$L_x(x_0,y_0) = Z_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $L_y(x_0,y_0) = Z_y(x_0,y_0)$

as required.

Comment: What is a tangent plane to a surface if not the plane spanned by all directional derivatives ?

Comment: I think this will depend on your source's exact definition of "tangent plane". This statement could sometimes be the definition itself. For other definitions, the proof is likely very simple.

Comment: Somewhere you need to use the actual definition of differentiability (continuous partial derivatives implies differentiable). What is your actual definition of the tangent plane? And, of course, the tangent plane is the graph $z=L(x,y)$.